# Truncate trail with AttributedString

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel in a cell, and I am setting attributed text in it. It attributed text is too large than it should come with ... at the end. How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func addTitle(title: String) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
    self.titleLabel.attributtedString = attributedTitle
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the above answers, maybe you forgot adding a trailing constraint to your UILabel or it's parent view.